# \COPY not printing count in psql

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, sh, psql

I am trying to copy CSV data into tables. Also I want to print the count.
The command I'm using is:

```
echo "begin; delete from a; \copy a from a.csv CSV HEADER; end;" | psql -hlocalhost -dpostgres -Upostgres
```

Expected Output:

```
BEGIN
DELETE 2
COPY 2
COMMIT
```

Actual Output:

```
BEGIN
DELETE 2
COMMIT
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your `\c` is eaten by the shell

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid quoting and escaping-trouble is to use a `HERE-document`:

---

```
#!/bin/sh

psql -hlocalhost -d postgres -U postgres << OMG
begin;
 SET search_path = tmp;
 delete from a;
 \copy a from 'a.csv' CSV HEADER;
end;
OMG
```

Comment: This works.. But any idea how to do this in single line?